# Unclear Mongoose error

Tags: coffeescript, mongoose

I get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at new SchemaArray (/home/campaigns/scheduler/tests/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/array.js:40:22)
at Function.interpretAsType (/home/campaigns/scheduler/tests/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:201:12)
at Schema.path (/home/campaigns/scheduler/tests/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:162:29)
at Schema.add (/home/campaigns/scheduler/tests/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:110:12)
at Schema.add (/home/campaigns/scheduler/tests/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:106:14)
at new Schema (/home/campaigns/scheduler/tests/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:38:10)
at Object. (/home/campaigns/scheduler/tests/testSchedulerModel.coffee:12:21)
at Object. (/home/campaigns/scheduler/tests/testSchedulerModel.coffee:177:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script.js:57:25)

However, on line 12 of testSchedulerModel.coffee there is no reference to 'name'. Here is what line 12 looks like:
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId

So how should I understand this error?

Thank you,
Igor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh. Unfortunately, while you'd *think* `testSchedulerModel.coffee:12` would mean "line 12 of `testSchedulerModel.coffee`, it actually means "line 12 of the JavaScript that `testSchedulerModel.coffee` is compiled to. The problem is that there's currently no way to trace errors back to the original CoffeeScript (at least not under Node).

So, you'll have to compile `testSchedulerModel.coffee` as JS and see what line 12 is there.

Better debugging tools for CoffeeScript are coming, but for now, it's probably best that you set up a Cakefile that compiles your code to JS before running it, to avoid such confusion.

By the way, there is an open issue regarding those `.coffee` filenames in the stack trace: [issue 987](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/987).

Comment: Thank you.  Makes me wonder if CoffeeScript is more of a headache than its worth sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Trevor: Kudos for the tip!

I solved my issue.  It turns out that I cannot have objects inside of arrays when defining my schema in Mongoose.  I was doing it like this:

```
AdUnitSchema = new mongoose.Schema
  venue: [
    {
      id: ObjectId,
      name: String
    }
  ],
  geotarget: [
    {
    id: ObjectId,
    name: String
    }
  ]
```

But in actuality, I had to create separate schemas, and reference them like this:

```
 AdUnitSchema = new mongoose.Schema
        venue:
          [VenueSchema]
        geotarget: 
          [GeotargetSchema]
```